# Copy the column of a signal from an input in MATLAB

Tags: matlab, input, signals

Ι have this function in MATLAB:

```
function X= frame_wind(x,frame,ovrlp,window)
```

where `x` is my signal (.wav file) and it is a table column. What i want to do is to copy this column to `N` which it will be a column again (obviously). I tried this:

```
function X= frame_wind(x,frame,ovrlp,window)
N=audioread(x);
...
...
...
end
```

but I keep getting an error:

> Not enough input arguments. 
>   
> Error in frame_wind (line 2)
>   
> N=audioread(x);

Could someone help me?

Comment: Did you read the documentation on [`audioread`](https://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/audioread.html)?  I'm not too familiar with the syntax, but it almost looks like N needs to be an array of two variables.

Comment: i read it and if i put N(x,1) for example still the problem exists

Comment: How are you calling `frame_wind`? Are you hitting F5 or the "Run" button or are you calling it from the command window?

Comment: from the command window... i wrote the input arguments and gives me the output